# find out if webview or native-view is used in android

Tags: android, webview, native

Is there a way to find out if a certain app on the market uses a webview/native-view other than getting hints from the looks?

I wonder if it's helpful to inspect networks, attach debugger, deserialize apk(?) if they are possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unzip the .apk with any tool like  winrar. If it's an html5-based app, you will see .html, .js and .css files in the `/res/assets` folder.

To get the `.apk`, pull it from your phone with adb. You might need root for this though.You can also use AirDroid to grab the .apk w/o root access.

A native app does not need to render views with XML file etc. I have native apps that programmatically create their layouts and views with only single root XML file that has a linear layout. I have native apps that create a web view and then populate the web view with content, and other views such as image views with their content. I would term such an app a hybrid. You can tell an app is based on PhoneGap et. al. by the large amount of JavaScript and the general clunkiness in their user interaction (my opinion).

Comment: Thanks, it helped. I'd like to add it was also useful to look at network packet, since, there are webapps which downloads htmls not just load from local files.